# How to extract specific values from a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like shown below and i would like to extract the partID and the corresponding quantity for a specific orderID using python, but i don't know how to do it.

```
dataList = [{'orderID': 'D00001', 'customerID': 'C00001', 'partID': 'P00001', 'quantity': 2},
 {'orderID': 'D00002', 'customerID': 'C00002', 'partID': 'P00002', 'quantity': 1},
 {'orderID': 'D00003', 'customerID': 'C00003', 'partID': 'P00001', 'quantity': 1},
 {'orderID': 'D00004', 'customerID': 'C00004', 'partID': 'P00003', 'quantity': 3}]
```

So for example, when i search my `dataList` for a specific `orderID == 'D00003'`, i would like to receive both the `partID ('P00001')`, as well as the corresponding `quantity (1)` of the specified order. How would you go about this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far i have tried to use the dict.get() function, but couldn't find a way to specify that i only need the partID, as well as the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

You are not going to do that a lot of time, you can just iterate over the list of dictionaries until you find the "correct" one:

```
search_for_order_id = 'D00001'
for d in dataList:
    if d['orderID'] == search_for_order_id:
        print(d['partID'], d['quantity'])
        break  # assuming orderID is unique
```

Outputs

```
P00001 2
```

Since this solution is O(n), if you are going to do this search a lot of times it will add up.

In that case it will be better to transform the data to a dictionary of dictionaries, with `orderID` being the outer key (again, assuming `orderID` is unique):

```
 better = {d['orderID']: d for d in dataList}
```

This is also O(n) but you pay it only once. Any subsequent lookup is an O(1) dictionary lookup:

```
search_for_order_id = 'D00001'
print(better[search_for_order_id]['partID'], better[search_for_order_id]['quantity'])
```

Also outputs

```
P00001 2
```

Comment: Hi DeepSpace, thank you very much for your quick help! Since i'm not going to need the this type of look up frequently i guess it would be ok to go for your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to familiarize yourself with the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) package, which is very useful for data analysis. If these are the kind of problems you're up against, I advise you to take the time and take a tutorial in `pandas`. It can do a lot, and is very popular.

Your `dataList` is very similar to a `DataFrame` structure, so what you're looking for would be as simple as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dataList)
df[df['orderID']=='D00003']
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Itamar, i will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the partID you can make use of the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function.

```py
myData = [{"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 5}]

filtered = filter(lambda item: item["x"] == 1) # Search for an object with x equal to 1

# Get the next item from the filter (the matching item) and get the y property.
print(next(filtered)["y"])
```

You should be able to apply this to your situation.

Comment: OP does not "need" to use `filter`. They can, but it definitely is not the only possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
results = [[x['orderID'], x['partID'], x['quantity']] for x in dataList]
for i in results:
    print(i)
```

Also,

```
results = [['Order ID: ' + x['orderID'], 'Part ID: ' + x['partID'],'Quantity: 
' + str(x['quantity'])] for x in dataList]
```